# Permalink changes gives me 404

Tags: permalinks

Up til now, I've used `/%postname%/`. Now I have changed this to `/%category%/%postname%/`. I know WP does not recommended to use category / psotname, but it makes a lot more sense for users.

Opening pages and posts work fine. What crashes are all my jQuery calls to jQuery.php file. The data is actually returned, but when trying to output the data, I get a 404 error.

Data process:

```
**Fetch data**  
Ajax request -> jQuery.php -> some.class.php -> database

**Return data**  
database -> some.class.php -> json_encode($result) -> 404 error
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? Do I have to change my `.htaccess` file?

**Update**

This is the .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Error message:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mysite/include/jquery.php?instance=search&limit=25&term=ac"

Respons tab in Firebug shows this:

```
[{"id":"221","value":"Acne","url_name":"Acne"},{"id":"7176","value":"Acne Jeans","url_name":"Acne+Jeans"}]
```

In this case I'm expecting a autosuggest answer.

If I paste this URL directly in browser, I get the result on the screen, but i **also** get a 404 error message.

This is a typical jQuery request:

```
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: siteURL +"/wp-content/themes/mysite/include/jquery.php",
        data: {
          instance: 'addPerson',
          name: 'Jon Doe',
          age: '26'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (function(data) {
          showFeedback(data);
        })
      });
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your issue? How are you getting a 404 error if the data is returned?

Comment: @m0r7if3r - That's what I don't understand. I can see the data in Firebug, but the jQuery to output my feedback stops working and Firebug says I have a 404 error.

Comment: As in you can see data coming out? Because if data is being returned and you have a 404, something WAY weird is going on.

Comment: @m0r7if3r - Yes, something weird is going on. If I paste this URL directly in the browser, the data is returned and outputted, but it also gives a 404 message...

Comment: Are you posting the request through `admin-ajax.php`?

Comment: @m0r7if3r - See update for typical jQuery ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Is your rewrite rule in your .htaccess well configured?
Can you post it here?

Should be configured like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Source:
[Codex page on pretty permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)